# ¿Cómo establecer dos valores en una etiqueta de opción? en Angular PrimeNG

Tags: angular, dropdownlist, dropdown

Quiero establecer dos valores en una etiqueta. Como ejemplo, si abro el menú desplegable, debería mostrarse como

```
jesus 63654587
erik 514569
jose 451587
etc
```

en una línea con el espacio.
los datos se obtienen de la base de datos.

```
p-dropdown [options]="sellers"
                            value='user.id'
                            formControlName="seller"
                            autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
                            filter="true"
                            optionLabel="{'user.name','user.phone'}"
                            ></p-dropdown>
                        <label for="inputtext">Vendedor</label>
```

Ayuda soy nuevo en angular!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar lo que es ng-template para poder armar a tu gusto el listado de tus items (el ejemplo de primeng lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

```
<p-dropdown
 [options]="sellers"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedSeller"
 placeholder="Select a Seller"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
    <div *ngIf="selectedSeller">
      <div>{{ selectedSeller.name }} - {{ selectedSeller.age }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-seller pTemplate="item">
    <div>
      <div>{{ seller.name }} - {{ seller.age }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: muchas gracias si funciono selo agradezco !!!!!!!!!!!!!